# python CGI script in <a href> tag doesn't execute

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am referencing a Python CGI script from another Python CGI script by using `<a href>` tag.
While it opens in a new tab in the browser, it doesn't execute by itself. However, when i refresh the tab, it does get executed.
By the way, i know that i could provide a `submit` button which could execute the script. However, i am using the script to download a file stored on the server and hence using **Content-Type:application/csv** and **Content-Disposition: attachment** HTTP headers

Comment: I hope you have a very good reason to be using CGI and hand crafted HTML in this day and age

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative? I had access to some pre-defined functions in CGI-Python and hence used those to get a page up quickly.

Comment: nowadays using django or flask is pretty much taken for granted when you use python and web in the same breath

Comment: Have a look at the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) for popular web frameworks.